# Upgrading the iphone/ipad enterprise app using Over The Air (OTA) distribution

Tags: iphone, ios4, ota

I am developing an application and i want to distribute it via over the air (which is introduced in iOS4 for enterprise apps).
I am able to send my app via OTA successfully, but i am facing a problem while upgrading the app.

I am using the same bundle identifier for the app upgradation and i am just changing the version of the app before building the application.

But, if I install the updated app on the device using OTA, it is upgrading the application but it is not retaining the data. [my app contains some downloaded pdf files which i am storing in NSCachedDirectory]. I am able to see the archived data in upgaraded app but the files which i have written to NSCachedDirectory i am not able to see.

I have tried using NSDocumentsDirectory as well, but i am getting the same result.
can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the amazing www.testflightapp.com to help you?
It works pretty well, keeps data for upgrades, and you can use it together with [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion), so you don't need to send emails to update your users.